# if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, show that $x^x\equiv a\pmod n$ always has a solution.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Recently, I became aware of this result:

$\textbf{Theorem 1:}$ if $n>1$ and $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^x \equiv a\pmod n$.

I found the proof of this theorem on this [page](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1301963p6940755) (at the bottom of the page), but I was not able to fully understand it, could you help me?

It goes as follow:

$\textbf{Proof 1:}$ let us introduce an intermediate lemma.

- $\textbf{Lemma:}$ if $m\in\mathbb{N}^*$ is such that $\gcd(m,\varphi(n))=1$, then $0^m,1^m,2^m,\dots,(n-1)^m$ is a permutation of $0,1,2,\dots, n-1$ (modulo $n$). ($\textbf{Edit:}$ as noticed by @metamorphy, the lemma only hold when $n$ is square-free)
- $\textbf{Proof of the lemma:}$ Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$. If $a,b$ are such that $a^m\equiv b^m\pmod{n}$, then in particular $a^m\equiv b^m\pmod{p}$. Because $\gcd(m,\varphi(n))=1$, we have $\gcd(m,\varphi(p))=1$, so there exists $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\lambda m + \mu \varphi(p) = 1$. As a result, $$a\equiv a^{\lambda m + \mu \varphi(p)}\equiv b^{\lambda m + \mu \varphi(p)}\equiv b\pmod{p}$$
  Note that we can lift $a$ and $b$ to the power $\lambda m$ and $\mu \varphi(p)$ because both $a$ and $b$ are $\equiv 0$ or they are both invertible modulo $p$ (as $p$ is a prime).
  *There, I don't understand how we conclude:*
  Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we conclude that $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$, which proves the lemma.

*I also don't understand the next part of Proof 1:* For every $m\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, let
$$\delta(m) :=\{m+p,m+2p,\dots, m+p(p-1), m+p^2\}\quad \pmod{\varphi(p) = p-1}$$
Consider all pairs (*which pairs? what does it precisely mean in this context?*) of equation $x^{m_1}\equiv a\pmod{p}$ where $m_1\in \delta(x)$. Clearly, all such $x$ work (*Why does it "clearly" work?*) and once we have obtained all pairs $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{w(n)}$ (*what is $w(n)$?*), we use Hensel's Lemma to lift these solutions to $p^{v_p(n)}$ (*How do we precisely apply Hensel Lemma here?*) and finish by Chinese Remainder Theorem.

$\textbf{End of Proof 1}$

As you can see, there are many point where I couldn't catch what the author wanted to say. It's been a few days and I still don't understand. If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't catch the problem well (and can't answer myself), but (+1) for the interesting subject and your serious effort.

Comment: What is the solution for $n=5$ and $a=3$?

Comment: $7^7 \equiv 2^7\equiv 2\cdot 4^3\equiv 2\cdot (-1)^3\equiv -2\equiv 3\pmod{5}$

Comment: Ok, I was thinking $x<n$ has no solution.

Comment: As stated, the **Lemma** is wrong. Take $n=4$ and $m=3$; then $$\gcd\big(3,\varphi(4)\big)=\gcd(3,2)=1,\quad\text{but}\quad 0^3\equiv 2^3\pmod{4}.$$

Comment: oh! You're right! So this proof cannot work for any $n$. I presume I have to add "$n$ is squarefree".

Comment: See **Corollary 4.3** [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241046455_ITERATED_EXPONENTS_IN_NUMBER_THEORY) (for a power tower $x^{x^{\,\cdot^{\,\cdot^{\,\cdot^{\,x}}}}}$ of an arbitrary height as well).

Comment: Thank you! The paper precisely answer to my question! I'll look into the details and write an answer to my own question when I've fully understood the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @metamorhpy, I found an answer to my question [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241046455_ITERATED_EXPONENTS_IN_NUMBER_THEORY). I detail it there.

We will prove that if $a\geq 0$ and $n\geq 0$ are integers such that $\gcd(a,n) =1$, then the equation $x^x \equiv a\pmod{n}$ always has a solution $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

We proceed by induction on the greatest prime divisor of $n$ (denoted by $\Omega_n$ in the following proof). We also denote the Chinese Remainder Theorem by CRT.

$\textbf{Initialisation:}$ For $n=1$, $a=0$ verifies $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, and $x=1$ works.

$\textbf{Induction:}$ Let $K>1$ be such that for all $n$ such that $\Omega_n<K$, for all $a\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $$\gcd(a,n)=1 \;\Rightarrow\; x^x\equiv a\pmod{n}\quad \text{has a solution.}$$
We take $n=p^k\cdot m$, where $\Omega_n = p$ is the smallest prime bigger than $K$, $k\geq 1$, and $\Omega_m < K$.
We also take $a\in \mathbb{N}$ which is relatively prime to $n$. We have $\gcd(a,m)=1$.
Moreover, let $r$ be the product of $q^{v_q(p-1)}$ where $q$ is a prime number that divides both $m$ and $p-1$.
$\gcd\left(\frac{p-1}{r},m\right) = 1$ so we can take $a\equiv 1\pmod{\frac{p-1}{r}}$. Applying CRT, we get that $\gcd(a,(p-1)m)=1$.
As $\Omega_{(p-1)m}<K$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x^x\equiv a\pmod{(p-1)m}$ $\color{red}{(i)}$.

We are now looking for $y\equiv x\pmod{(p-1)m\cdot\varphi((p-1)m)}$ $\color{red}{(ii)}$ such that $y^y\equiv a\pmod{p^k}$.
Notice that $\color{red}{(ii)}$ implies $y^y\equiv a\pmod{m}$.
$\color{red}{(ii)}$ also implies that $y\equiv x\pmod{p-1}$, so $y^y\equiv a\pmod{p}$ is equivalent to $y^x\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Considering that $\gcd(x,p) = 1$, $y\mapsto y^x$ is a bijection modulo $p$, so there exists a unique $y_1$ modulo $p$ such that $y_1^{y_1}\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

We are now looking for $y$ such that $y\equiv x\pmod{(p-1)m\cdot\varphi((p-1)m)}$ and $y\equiv y_1\pmod{p}$.
The two conditions $y\equiv x\pmod{p-1}$ and $y\equiv y_1\pmod{p}$ merge into $y\equiv a_1\pmod{p(p-1)}$ where $x_1$ is inversible modulo $p(p-1)$ and is given by CRT. $y^y\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$ becomes $y^{x_1}\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$, which has a unique solution $y_2$ (again, because $x_1$ is relatively prime to $p^2$, so $y\mapsto y^{x_1}$ is a bijection from and to the group of invertibles modulo $p^2$.)

Following this process, we find $y_1,y_2,\dots, y_k$, with at last $$
y\equiv y_k\pmod{p^k}\quad \Rightarrow\quad y^{y}\equiv a\pmod{p^k}$$
Using CRT (remember that we already have $y^y\equiv a\pmod{m}$), we are able to construct $y$ such that $y^y\equiv a\pmod{p^k\cdot m = n}$, which concludes the proof.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad english.